# clear one session value after 30 minutes in angular js

Tags: angularjs, timeout

I want to clear a session value after 30 minutes, not entire session values, just one session value.

```
var reqestTimeOut  =  $timeout(localValue = '', 30000);
```

Comment: Will this work.. Anyone can help me to get a suggestion...

Comment: 30000 is 30 seconds, not 30 minutes. Why don't you test it?

Answer (score 1):

> use $timeout like this sample

```
$timeout(function(){
  localValue = "";
}, 30000)
```